# Is there a keyboard shortcut (that doesn't involve arrow keys) for selecting a Google search result?

Tags: youtube, google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

Using YouTube or Google search prompts us with multiple intelligent results that are only accessible with the mouse or the arrow keys. Is there a way or a hack to allow selection of results?

Using a Mac,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> makes it swap last two typed chars
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> is similar to pressing return
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> places the cursor in the beginning
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> places the cursor in the end

There seems to be no way to select results other than arrow keys, which is a pain for any emacs/vi user.

Example: go to amazon.com, type "plays" on their search box, the search box proposes playstation 4, playstation network, playstation gift card etc...
There is no way to select those options other than the arrow keys.

Comment: What do you mean select the results? Do you mean select all at once, or are you fine selecting one option at a time (perhaps, open the selected result in a new tab)?

Comment: How do you browse google.com, youtube.com, amazon.com using chrome or safari? they all have a search box right? they all have a smart autocomplete, like typing "why are dogs" it will automatically provide options, today for example it provides "why are dogs better than cats" as first option, now my question is how do you select that option without using the mouse or having to move your hand to the arrow keys?

There seems to be no way...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.  Pressing it repeatedly scrolls down the page, from the search bar and toolbars, down to focusable items on the current page.

Comment: Correct, however I was asking about selecting a proposed smart completion from the search box.
Example: got to amazon.com, type "plays" on their search box, the search box proposes playstation 4, playstation network, playstation gift card etc...
There is no way to select those options that doesn't involve the mouse or the arrow keys.

Now if you use safari and you type "plays" in the address bar you can actually cycle all options using ctrl+n or ctrl+p as you do in emacs or vim completion or sublime completion or Xcode...